# Xcode three tab project with three different projects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, merge, nstabviewcontroller

I wonder if someone could guid me right direction please.

I got three different projects all built separately on Xcode 6.1.1 and objective C. I want to put all these three project under one.

[image]

This new project is made up of three tabs having one project each. All three project run independently and do not share any data.

whats is the best approach?

Comment: you're not going to get that to work as you're asking. you can open one of the projects and then add the others to its workspace. you'll have access to all of the associate files, but you'll still need to write the code to make it into a single, cohesive app

Comment: thanks. I have created project with three tabs and going to add all three projects to tab project workspace, create instances of each project and assign it to a tab.